# Epic and Legendary badges only for standard rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

Not that I'm anywhere near it, in fact today was the first time I hit 200 daily rep without a bounty pushing me over, and it got me wondering: for the [Epic](https://android.stackexchange.com/badges/26/epic) and [Legendary](https://android.stackexchange.com/badges/27/legendary) badges, do 200+ days accomplished with non-limited reputation points (accepted answers, bounties, etc.) count toward these, if you wouldn't have broken 200 daily rep without them?

If so, should their descriptions be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hitting the upvote rep cap is not necessary for a given day to count towards those badges, you simply have to earn >=200 rep by any means. Taken from MSO's "[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/150283)":

> #### Epic
>
> - silver; awarded once; same family as Mortarboard (bronze), Legendary (gold)
> - Earned more than 200 reputation on 50 days
>
>   - Reputation source can be any vote type, upvotes, accepted answers, bounties...any net increase from votes (not association) totaling >=
>       200.
>   - Each "day" lasts from midnight UTC to immediately before midnight, UTC; days are **not** counted in local time
> - Sources: [Is 150 "rep cap exceeded" *alone* enough for Legendary badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge),
>     which includes [the actual query that produces the
>     badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge/58192#58192)
>     in an answer by Jeff, [How is it possible to exceed the rep cap
>     without reaching
>     it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/how-is-it-possible-to-exceed-the-rep-cap-without-reaching-it/49405#49405),
>     which features more human-readable comments by Jeff, Nick Craver's
>     edit to the definition of Mortarboard, below, and research explained
>     at [this
>     post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78867/how-is-it-possible-to-reach-the-rep-cap-without-exceeding-it/82796#82796).

The description of the Legendary badge notes the same rep requirements. Given this, the description is (IMHO) accurate.